# Invalid webservice adapter specified REST API

Tags: product, customer, api, rest-api, soap-api-v2

I have configured the rest api in my localhost magento. When I Hit this url, `http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products`

The error is:

> Invalid webservice adapter specified.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Can u tell  me where can we find & change this piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

This errors comes from here: \Mage_Api_Model_Server::initialize

You are using the rest adapter, which is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc/api.xml`

```
    <adapters>
        <soap>
            <model>api/server_adapter_soap</model>
            <handler>default</handler>
            <active>1</active>
            <required>
                <extensions>
                    <soap />
                </extensions>
            </required>
        </soap>
        <soap_v2>
            <model>api/server_v2_adapter_soap</model>
            <handler>soap_v2</handler>
            <active>1</active>
            <required>
                <extensions>
                    <soap />
                </extensions>
            </required>
        </soap_v2>
        <soap_wsi>
            <model>api/server_wsi_adapter_soap</model>
            <handler>soap_wsi</handler>
            <active>1</active>
            <required>
                <extensions>
                    <soap />
                </extensions>
            </required>
        </soap_wsi>
        <xmlrpc>
            <model>api/server_adapter_xmlrpc</model>
            <handler>default</handler>
            <active>1</active>
        </xmlrpc>
        <default>
            <use>soap</use>
        </default>
    </adapters>
```

It might help to uncomment the line in `.htaccess`

```
############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Its already un commented. However it is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution fixed the issue for me.

If you're sure you have the following line uncomented in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

...and it still does not work, then please be sure you have **turned off MultiViews option** in apache. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName magento.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/magento"
    <Directory  "c:/www/magento/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Pay attention to **-MultiViews** above.